# How to send mails by getting the details from admin

Tags: magento-1.8

I had created the form and I need to send the three mails at a time i.e

1.One for customer

2.One for admin

3.One for the service providers emails for those 'isbloodonor' is true and save the customer as new service provider.

I can send 1,2 but 3rd one is not able to send.Please help me.

My mail code which I have tested for 1 and 2.

```
<?php
//Admin Mail
  function sendMailAction(){
    //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
   $email=$_POST['email'];
   $bloodgroup=$_POST['bloodgroup'];
 $unitsrequired=$_POST['unitsrequired'];
  $requireddate=$_POST['requiredby'];
  $city=$_POST['city'];
 $hospital=$_POST['hospital'];
 //$location=$_POST['location'];

    $name=$_POST['name'];
   $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];

   $html=
  '<p>Bloodgroup: '.$bloodgroup.'</p>
  <p>Units Required:'.$unitsrequired.'</p>
   <p>Required By:'.$requiredby.'</p>
  <p>City: '.$city.'</p>

   <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
   <p>Email : '.$email.'</p>
   <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>'


  ;
  $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
    $mail->setToName($name);
   $mail->setToEmail($email);
   $mail->setBody($html);
   $mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
   $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
   $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
  //$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
     $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

     try {
     $mail->send();
     //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
         //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
         //return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
      //$this->_redirect('');
     }
        catch (Exception $e) {
      //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
       //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
      //return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
      //$this->_redirect('');
        }
      }
         //Customer Mail

        function sendMailcustomerAction(){
          //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
            $name=$_POST['name'];
           $email=$_POST['email'];
              $bloodgroup=$_POST['bloodgroup'];
         $unitsrequired=$_POST['unitsrequired'];
          $requireddate=$_POST['requiredby'];
          $city=$_POST['city'];
            $hospital=$_POST['hospital'];

           $html=
         'Dear '.$name.',

             <p>We have received your order for '.$bloodgroup.' .  You                  will be attended shortly.</p>

           <p>Best Regards,</p>
           <p>Team Labwise.</p>'

      ;
         $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
          $mail->setToName($cname);
           $mail->setToEmail($email);
          $mail->setBody($html);
        $mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
        $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
        $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
         //$mail->addBcc("contact@labwise.in");
         $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

          try {
          $mail->send();
           //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is    successfully Completed');
           //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
            return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
          //$this->_redirect('');
           }
          catch (Exception $e) {
           //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
          //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
        return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>';
      //$this->_redirect('');
        }
       }

       //service provider details:

  $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');  
    $allrecord =    $readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isblooddonor=?', '1'
      );
     $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
     foreach($alldata as $data)
     {
        sendMailserviceAction($data['email']);
     }

     function sendMailserviceAction($email){
 //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
 $cemail=$_POST['email'];
 $bloodgroup=$_POST['bloodgroup'];
 $unitsrequired=$_POST['unitsrequired'];
 $requireddate=$_POST['requiredby'];
 $scity=$_POST['city'];
 $hospital=$_POST['hospital'];
 //$location=$_POST['location'];

 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];

 $html=
'<p>Bloodgroup: '.$bloodgroup.'</p>
 <p>Units Required:'.$unitsrequired.'</p>
 <p>Required By:'.$requiredby.'</p>
 <p>City: '.$scity.'</p>

 <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
 <p>Email : '.$cemail.'</p>
 <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>'


;
 $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
 $mail->setToName($name);
 $mail->setToEmail($email);
 $mail->setBody($html);
 $mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
 $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
 $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
//$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
$mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
  $mail->send();
  //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
  //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
  //$this->_redirect('');
  }
 catch (Exception $e) {
  //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
   //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
  return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
 //$this->_redirect('');
 }
 }
 echo sendMailserviceAction();
  echo sendMailcustomerAction();
 echo sendMailAction();

$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');
 $emailcust=$_POST['email'];
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $scity=$_POST['scity'];
 $yourbloodgroup=$_POST['yourbloodgroup'];
 $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
 if($_POST['isblooddonor']) {
         $query = "insert into mg_serviceprovider "
                     . "(email,name, city,mobile) values "
                     . "(:email, :name, :city,:mobile)";

              $binds = array(
                  'email'    => $email,
                  'name'   => $name,
                  'city' => $scity,
                  'mobile' => $mobile,


              );

              $connectionWrite->query($query, $binds); }

    ?>
```

Comment: can you share your mail send code?

Comment: Added the mail code.Please review it

Comment: @Abdul added the code.Please check it.It is very important for me.

Comment: are you sending 3rd email same as 1 & 2 email?

Comment: yes but is not working

Comment: can you check bellow code :$html = "isbloodonor";
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName($singleserviceprovideName);
$mail->setToEmail($singleserviceprovideemail);
$mail->setBody($html);
$mail->setSubject($singleserviceprovideSubject);
$mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
$mail->setFromName("Labwise");
//$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
$mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
  $mail->send();
   return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. </h2>';
  }
 catch (Exception $e) {
  return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
 }

Comment: html content same but change service provide name & email

Comment: I need to send only for mail ids of service provider

Comment: could you please in my code.it is getting confusion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31350/discussion-between-abdul-and-mouni).

Comment: Hey please reply me.It is very important for me.

Comment: You need to send all $allserviceproviders = $this->getLabs();  content  in single mail or saparet mail?

Comment: 1) Please discuss in chat. 2) Closing because it's too broad and the code is desperately out of shape, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send email like that

```
 <?php
            $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');  
            $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('serviceprovider'=>'mg_serviceprovider'))->where('serviceprovider.isblooddonor=?', '1'
              );
             $alldata =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);
             foreach($alldata as $data)
             {
                sendMailAction($data['email'],$data['name']);
             }

              function sendMailAction($email,$pname){
         //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);

          $bloodgroup=$_POST['bloodgroup'];
$emailcust=$_POST['email'];
          $unitsrequired=$_POST['unitsrequired'];
          $requireddate=$_POST['requiredby'];
         $city=$_POST['city'];
         $hospital=$_POST['hospital'];
         //$location=$_POST['location'];

         $name=$_POST['name'];
         $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];

         $html=
        '<p>Bloodgroup: '.$bloodgroup.'</p>
         <p>Units Required:'.$unitsrequired.'</p>
         <p>Required By:'.$requiredby.'</p>
         <p>City: '.$city.'</p>

         <p>Name: '.$name.'</p>
         <p>Email : '.$emailcust.'</p>
         <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>'


        ;
         $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
           $mail->setToName($pname);
        $mail->setToEmail($email);
        $mail->setBody($html);
        $mail->setSubject('Blood Donor');
        $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
        $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
        //$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
        $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

           try {
          $mail->send();
          //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
          //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
        return '';
          //$this->_redirect('');
          }
         catch (Exception $e) {
          //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
           //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
          return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
         //$this->_redirect('');
         }
         }
      echo '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';  
             ?>
```

this is code for saving the provider

```
 <?php 
            $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');
        $email=$_POST['email'];
  $name=$_POST['testname'];
   $city=$_POST['city'];
   $location=$_POST['location'];

    $cname=$_POST['cname'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
 if($_POST['isblooddonor']) {
            $query = "insert into mg_serviceprovider "
                         . "(email,testname, city, location, cname, mobile) values "
                         . "(:email, :testname, :city, :location, :cname, :mobile)";

                  $binds = array(
                      'email'    => $email,
                      'testname'   => $name,
                      'city' => $city,
                      'location' => $location,
                      'cname' => $cname,
                      'mobile' => $mobile,

                  );

                  $connectionWrite->query($query, $binds); } ?>
```

Comment: Ok how can I save the customer as a service provider

Comment: I need to add in the same file which i am using for sending  the 2 mails

Comment: I am getting the mails but confirmation message is not displaying

Comment: because you have to add data in that.. you are posting in form

Comment: sorry can you explain me.Which data I need to add

Comment: the data you want to send in email. add in $html

Comment: Sorry.I am talking about customer details has to save in the service provider list.

Comment: for checkbox it has to be true for the new customer.

Comment: add if($checkbox) {  //add mew customer code here }

Comment: In which file I need to add in the same mail file or need to create a new file

Comment: where you are posting the form.

Comment: Can you please add these checkbox code in service provider code.I am not getting where I have to place the code.

Comment: In the same folder where the mail file exists

Comment: yes if they are submitting there then add it there..

Comment: I am talking about the saving the provider code.It has to be placed in the mail code

Comment: yes place it there

Comment: can you please edit with checkbox code

Comment: checkbox field name is?

Comment: checkbox name: isblooddonor

Comment: check now is this your requirement

Comment: with the true checkbox the customer details has to be saved

Comment: yes it will work like that

Comment: while inserting the customer fields the checkbox value is to be 1

Comment: 1 is equal to true so the condition is work only it's value is 1

Comment: Ok and in service provider mail in subject it is not taking customer email it is taking service provider email.Can you please check.

Comment: where is customer email. if you posting add you post value there

Comment: Ok.The confirmation message is not printing for sending mail for service provider

Comment: update the answer kindly check it

Comment: Ok.The confirmation message is not display

Comment: $emailcust=$_POST['email']; the user is adding email in form or not

Comment: yes it is working after submiting form the confirmation is not displaying but the mails are getting

Comment: where is confirmation?

Comment: confirmation message  "Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.".This is not displaying after submission

Comment: add it after the loop because it will not show so show it like i add in code. hope this will solve ur problem

Comment: If the mail has not send how it will display

Comment: leave that because that message is for admin side not for user side

Comment: Ok.we had a dropdown list in service provider also and in the form.the selected drodown should also save in the service provider

Comment: so save add column name and post value name in submit query.

Comment: I have added the image.Please review it the customer details has to save in the service provider in the same way.

Comment: you need to upload the image first then save to database it not easy works post this question separately

Comment: I am talking about checkbox and dropdown list it has to be with the same fields the name,email and mobile,isblooddonr and bloodgroup has to be added to the service provider with the new customer details

Comment: yes you add can add all form field with customer

Comment: is your code works which you have posted before

Comment: for inserting the customer??

Comment: yes with the details email,name,mobile,city,isbloodonor and blood group

Comment: you are talking about default customer of magento?

Comment: No not that the service provider form.The mail details are to be saved as the new service provider in admin

Comment: i already give you code use it and make changes in that

Comment: it is not working.The details are not adding

Comment: update answer check it now

Comment: i will check it one more thing $mail->setToName($name);it is taking customer name.it has to take service provider name.

Comment: update the answer on ur requirement

Comment: could you please check my code and if there is any error.please suggest me.

Comment: no i could not find any error

Comment: but the provider is not creating

Comment: email,testname, city, location, cname, mobile check these column name are correct

Comment: I changed the code as per the columns available in the table.Please check recently updated code.

Comment: now it look perfect...

Comment: what you have changed.

Comment: i am talking about ur code

Comment: But why the provider is not saving in admin

Comment: replace and clear ur cahce and check then `$binds = array(
                  'email'    => $emailcust,
                  'name'   => $name,
                  'city' => $scity,
                  'mobile' => $mobile,


              );`

Comment: It could not send a mail also by adding the provider saving code in mail file

Comment: i think there is error on ur index.php in rooot uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1); remove # and check the error

Comment: It is showing error the admin panel is not opening

Comment: paste the error here

Comment: Warning: require(/home/labwise0/public_html/devel/app/bootstrap.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/labwise0/public_html/devel/index.php on line 64

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/labwise0/public_html/devel/app/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php53/pear') in /home/labwise0/public_html/devel/index.php on line 64

Comment: disable it u already have big problem...

Comment: comment line one by one and find where the error occur

Comment: ok.I will try can you give your mail id.If there is any problem i will mail you

Comment: i am here just comment ur problem ready to help..

Comment: Actually I am leaving now.I will take up this by night because of that I am asking you.